# why a single-only existing relation between fact-table & dim-table is inactive --AdventureWorksDW

Tags: powerbi

I have a situation -- I noticed that the only exisiting-single relation between the (Fact-table) FactResellerSales and DimReseller (dimension table) is inactive. I happen to notice it as I am unable to filter FactResellerSales -- total-sales by a Reseller-column in DimResller-table -- as I get the same total across all the Resellers in the row.

My concern is, what could the scenarios a relation could be inactive other than when there are multiple-relations between a given fact-table and dimension-table?

Would anyone please help me understand the scenario? Please find the screenshot of the model. Thank you for giving your valuable time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what could the scenarios a relation could be inactive other than when there are multiple-relations between a given fact-table and dimension-table?

Cycles that create ambiguous filter flow are also not allowed.

Here there's already a path `DimSalesTerritory -- > DimEmployee --> FactResellerSales`. If the relationship were active, you'd also have `DimSalesTerritory --> DimGeography --> DimReseller --> FactResellerSale`.

So when displaying Total Sales for Northeast, do you mean total sales for all Employees in Northeast or total sales for all Resellers in the Northeast?  You resolve this ambiguity by disabling one or the other relathionshp.

Comment: There's already a path `DimSalesTerritory -- > DimEmployee --> FactResellerSales`. If the relationship were active, you'd also have `DimSalesTerritory --> DimGeography --> DimReseller --> FactResellerSales`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, David!